# Add new tag to current payload

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 esb-4.9.0

I have below the payload.

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<msg>Body1</msg>
<msg>Body2</msg>
<msg>Body3</msg>
</note>
```

I want to add below new tag before every msg tag.

```
<?xml-multiple  msg?>
```

Currently, I'm doing that with the help of XSLT mediator. Is there a way to add above tag, without using a XSLT mediator or script mediator?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the XSLT mediator to do this? It would be the easiest way. Also do you want it before every msg tag or just before the group of msg tags. If you are converting the XML to JSON you only need the xml-multiple once before the group of msg tags.

Comment: I don't think without using XSLT this can be achieved,  <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple"/>  has to be used for inserting the xml-multiple tag